# AWS RDS - Bottleneck

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Working with AWS RDS for a couple of days right now, and i am a little underwhelmed by the time it takes to connect to the AWS RDS i did setup. My AWS RDS Server is a `db.r5.large`, in the same region as my original server (another hoster - not amazon), but the plain connection time takes about 200 ms. I get about the same result from my local machine, connecting to the AWS RDS.

Is there something i can turn on / off in the settings, or generally spoken something i should try to improve the 200 ms? I would love to face under 50 ms. I was thinking about moving my other Server to AWS EC2, and making them share a private network, which would probably shape off some ms..?

Comment: Which RDS engine? MySQL? PostgreSQL? Aurora or not?

Comment: It is Aurora with PostgreSQL dialect Version 10.7

Comment: Did you evaluate the latency for an EC2 inside the same subnet ? To be sure it is not this specific setting.

Comment: As i have no EC2 instance - no i did not. That's why i am thinking about it.

Comment: Hey, are you connecting to your RDS instance using the private IP or using the public IP?

Comment: I am using the public IP, moreover the hostname.